# Classpath Issue with Eclipse and Linux from a Virtual Machine

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, hbase, classpath

I have some java code on eclipse and I want to sent it to a virtual machine that runs the linux command line. I'm learning HBase through a MapR.com tutorial and it says once I'm logged into the Virtual Machine, run this command to run the program:

```
java -cp `hbase classpath`:./lab-exercises-shopping-1.0.jar shopping.ShoppingCartApp setup
```

When I run that in the appropriate directory:

```
[user01@maprdemo target]$ java -cp `hbase classpath`:./lab-exercises-shopping-1.0.jar shopping.ShoppingCartApp setup
```

I get this error:

`[user01@maprdemo target]$ java -cp 'hbase classpath':./lab-exercises-shopping-1.0.jar shopping.ShoppingCartApp setup
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more`

I believe - and please let me know if I'm wrong - that `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class was found at compilation but not here right? But I know that the class is there because in my original directory (Not sure if that has a name).

```
ls lab-exercises-shopping/target:
classes      lab-exercises-shopping-1.0.jar   (among other things)

ls lab-exercises-shopping/target/classes/shopping:
dao   InitTables.class   model   ShoppingCartApp.class    ShoppingCartTool.class
```

When I type in: hbase classpath:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3pdv.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vkJm.png)

I'm pretty new at this and don't really know what I'm talking about but I'm trying to learn so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Also if someone can explain some other things too that would help:
Is there a difference between a classpath and HBase classpath?
Where can I find the/all classpaths?

UPDATE: I did the exact same thing in Putty and it did something different:
`WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Creating  table...
 table created.
Creating  table...
 table created.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at shopping.ShoppingCartApp.main(ShoppingCartApp.java:32)`

The PDF instructions tell me: 
Note: If you see the following warning messages, then set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as shown here.
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...
using builtin-java classes where applicable
INFO security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Falling back to shell based
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/native/Linuxamd64-64

So I tried that code and ran it again and it kind of helped but in the output below, there should be three rows inserted, not two:

```
WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 table already exists.
 table already exists.
in init ...
------------------------------
 Inserting rows in Inventory Table:
mkPut   [Inventory [key=pens, quantity=9]]
mkPut   [Inventory [key=notepads, quantity=21]]
2017-01-17 11:13:16,777 INFO  [main] client.HTable: BufferedMutator Use HBase ThreadPool
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getBufferedMutator(HTable.java:2349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1311)
        at shopping.dao.InventoryDAO.addInventory(InventoryDAO.java:103)
        at shopping.ShoppingCartApp.saveInventoryTableData(ShoppingCartApp.java:89)
        at shopping.ShoppingCartApp.main(ShoppingCartApp.java:36)
```

Comment: I believe you've a typo ... there no difference between `-cp` and `-classpath` ... both define the same thing ... about the `NoClassDefFoundError`, it means that your classpath is missing the class: org/apache/hadoop/conf/configuration ... So, you must configure your classpath variable to hold the required external libraries...

Comment: @CarlitosWay Where can I find the classpath variable and how would I go about configuring it?

Comment: `-cp` is your classpath variable... what do you get when you execute the commnad: `$ hbase classpath` ??

Comment: @CarlitosWay I edited my post and included screen shots of what happens when I run $ hbase classpath

Comment: Two things... first, post the full stacktrace error to understand more what is happening... second, the hadoop library should be included at your classpath... do you know if hadoop is being used by `hbase` or your shopping exercise example?

Comment: @CarlitosWay I updated the stacktrace error on the post. I believe hadoop is being used but I'm not sure. The example is doing basic CRUD with Java to use the HTableInterface to communicate with an HBase table. But HBase tables store their data in the BlockCache, Memstore, and HDFS. The third being Hadoop right? Please tell me if I'm wrong, I just want to learn this.

Comment: Yes, according to [this](https://hbase.apache.org/) and [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/) you're using hadoop ... Now, according to [jarFinder](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html), the missing class is at a jar file called: `hadoop-core-xxxx.jar` ... if you execute the cmd: `hbase classpath | grep hadoop-core`, do you see the library ?? If not, I believe that hbase is incomplete (bad installed) ... If yes, probably you're running your demo app with an user that does not have privilege of reading on the hbase app libraries (use `chmod` in this case)...

Comment: @CarlitosWay `[user01@maprdemo target]$ hbase classpath | grep hadoop-core`

`[user01@maprdemo target]$`
Nothing comes up when I type that in. Does that mean that I have to download the whole program again? Or can I just download that jar?

Comment: I just download the last version of `hbase` (1.3) and the library: `hadoop-common-xxx.jar` which is found at the lib folder, have the class that seems to be missing (`org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`) ... so, my guess is that you have problems with reading permissions ... does your linux user have read permission at the directory: `/opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-1.1.1/lib` ??

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I find that out?

Comment: execute: `ls -l  /opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-1.1.1/lib` ...

Comment: I executed it and got a long list of jars. Pretty much all of them have
 -rw-r--r--
I appreciate you helping me btw. I clearly don't know what I'm doing

Comment: It seems right.... Have you try to install a newer version of `hbase`??

Comment: [Link](http://learn.mapr.com/dev-330-developing-hbase-applications-basics/21492#)
I tried re installing it but that didn't work. The link is the pdf instructions for what I'm supposed to be doing. I'm stuck on page 75. I hope that helps

Comment: UPDATED POST ABOVE

Comment: No Clue... but that `NullPointerException`, that shows when inserting data, is not a good sign... may be that's why you only get 2 insertions and not three....

Comment: UPDATE: I'm still not sure why I'm getting:
`WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop` `library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

But I found an error in my java code and everything seems to be working fine now.